# Google Chart's Column Annotations don't Fit

Tags: java, charts, annotations, google-visualization

http://s18.postimg.org/oex83yh61/Screen_Shot_2015_04_26_at_2_48_07_pm.png

I am trying to create an annotated stacked column chart with Google's Chart API. However, I cannot get the annotations to display properly. When an annotation is too big to sit inside the column, it is apparently supposed to display on top (which it has here, for columns 1,2,3 and 7). However, instead of doing this consistently I get many annotations represent as  '...' (which is obviously useless).

All the annotations are 2-3 digit numbers, so there is no reason for them not to fit. Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround by formatting the annotations? I have tried adjusting font-size but the same behaviour occurs until the font is imperceptibly small (1 or 2pt).

This used to work in Image Charts API, but I am trying to move to the new API and can't get past this annotation issue. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out finally, so for anyone who is interested the trick is essentially to use a ComboChart. Instead of directly annotating the columns, you add an invisible line series with the same data (lineWidth: 0), and then annotate the line.

This JSFiddle by Andrew Gallant illustrates...
http://jfiddle.net/asgallant/QjQNX/

With little manipulation, this can be made to work with stacked column charts as well.

Furthermore, if you want to get rid of the tick marks you can use javascript to set all svg rect elements of width=1 to have width=0